# Classpath does not work under linux

Tags: java, linux, classpath

Anyone have an idea why this command works fine in Windows but in Linux I get a ClassNotFoundException game.ui.Main

```
java -cp ".;lib/*" game.ui.Main -Xms64m -Xmx128m
```

my folder structure looks like this:
lib/ - Jars
game/ - Class files

This is the latest Java 6.

Comment: Why `/*` is necessary?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

The classpath syntax is OS-dependent. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29) :

> Being closely associated with the file
>   system, the command-line Classpath
>   syntax depends on the operating
>   system. For example:
>
> on all Unix-like operating systems
>   (such as Linux and Mac OS X), the
>   directory structure has a Unix syntax,
>   with separate file paths separated by
>   a colon (":").
>
> on Windows, the directory structure
>   has a Windows syntax, and each file
>   path must be separated by a semicolon
>   (";").
>
> This does not apply when the Classpath
>   is defined in manifest files, where
>   each file path must be separated by a
>   space (" "), regardless of the
>   operating system.

Comment: Yes. Thanks. My eyes are going. It looked like a semi on the web page I was checking. :)

Comment: Anyone still around that can tell me how to figure this out in a script? like a python or shell script? so that I can run a script using a "platform independent" scripting language to start a program written in a "platform independent" compiled language?

Comment: @CodeJockey: You can test for the existence of a directory that would exist only on Windows, or check one of the env variables that would only be set on Windows (PUBLIC, COMMONPROGRAMFILES, USERDOMAIN, ...).

Answer (score 34):

Try changing the semi-colon to a colon.

The CLASSPATH separator is platform dependent, and is the same as the character returned by [java.io.File.pathSeparatorChar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#pathSeparatorChar).

Answer (score 8):

**Windows:**

`java -cp file.jar;dir/* my.app.ClassName`

**Linux:**

`java -cp file.jar:dir/* my.app.ClassName`

**Remind:**

- Windows path separator is `;`
- Linux path separator is `:`
- In Windows if cp argument does not contains white space, the quotes is optional

Answer (score 4):

Paths are important too when using classpaths in scripts meant to be run on both platforms: Windows (i.e. cygwin) and Linux.  When I do this I include a function like this for the classpath.  The 'cygpath' command with the '-w' option converts paths to Windows-style paths.  So in this example "/home/user/lib/this.jar" would be converted to something like "C:\Cygwin\home\user\lib\this.jar"

```
#!/bin/bash

function add_java_classpath() {
  local LOCAL1=$1
  if [ "$OSTYPE" == cygwin ]; then
    LOCAL1="$(cygpath -C ANSI -w $LOCAL1)"
  fi
  if [ -z "$JAVA_CLASSPATH" ]; then
    JAVA_CLASSPATH="$LOCAL1"
  elif [ "$OSTYPE" != cygwin ]; then
    JAVA_CLASSPATH="${JAVA_CLASSPATH}:$LOCAL1"
  else
    JAVA_CLASSPATH="${JAVA_CLASSPATH};$LOCAL1"
  fi      
}

add_java_classpath /home/user/lib/this.jar
add_java_classpath /usr/local/lib/that/that.jar

java -cp "${JAVA_CLASSPATH}" package.Main $@
```