# Java - NoClassDefFoundError on running

Tags: java

Today I tried to compile my sources through the command prompt:

```
PS ...\JavaDev\Prog> javac -classpath <libs> -d . -sourcepath src src/com/negi/prog/Prog.java
```

They compiled successfully.

But when I try to run it, it produces an error:

```
PS ...\JavaDev\Prog> java -classpath  com.negi.prog.Prog

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/negi/prog/Prog
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.negi.prog.Prog
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classes in your `-classpath` have to be separated by `:`

```
PS ...\JavaDev\Prog> java -classpath "<libs>:com.negi.prog.Prog"
```

To complete the answer, the different operating systems have different classpath separators. You can check the separator by retrieving the value of the `java.class.path` property.

Comment: Actually different operating systems have different classpath seporators thus the `java.class.path` property in [System](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html).

Comment: Since he's on Windows (judging by use of the back slash instead of forward slash) he needs to use `;`. [Relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528438/classpath-does-not-work-under-linux).

Comment: Correct. But my guess was this is the reason the class is not included in the classpath.

Comment: @kocko Absolutely, your answer is correct, just making sure we get complete information.

Answer (score 2):

By default . (current path) is included in class path, but if you specify -classpath or -cp, then that is overridden. Include . in your classpath:

```
java -classpath <libs>:. com.negi.prog.Prog
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure the current directory is on the classpath when running i.e.

```
PS ...\JavaDev\Prog> java -classpath <libs>:. com.negi.prog.Prog
```