# Can't execute from command line

Tags: java

I can successfully execute from Eclipse IDE, but when trying to execute a java .class file from Terminal I'm having some issues.

Pertinent files reside as:

`~/dropbox/workspace/mysqltut/src/zetcode/Version.java`
`~/dropbox/workspace/mysqltut/src/zetcode/Version.class`
`~/dropbox/workspace/mysqltut/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jar`

After navigating to `~/dropbox/workspace/mysqltut/src/` in Terminal, I run the following:

`java -cp .:lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jar zetcode/Version`

```
May 02, 2014 10:54:31 PM zetcode.Version main
SEVERE: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:596)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
    at zetcode.Version.main(Version.java:24)
```

Is something wrong with my syntax/file structure or is something not installed properly?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should navigate to `~/dropbox/workspace/mysqltut/` and start your commands from it.
Use semicolon as the delimiter between the jar files or class folders

`java -cp lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jar;src zetcode.Version`

The delimiter is OS dependent. It is discussed here [Classpath does not work under linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528438/classpath-does-not-work-under-linux)

Comment: that's not proper syntax though.  The syntax is `java [options] [source class]`  If I use what you suggested, it comes back with `-bash: src: command not found.`   `java -cp lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jar ; src/zetcode/Version` comes back with `-bash: src/zetcode/Version: No such file or directory`  And if I remove the semicolon altogether and use `java -cp lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jar src/zetcode/Version` I get Error:  Could not find or load main class src.zetcode.Version` I believe u have to start in the package folder.  Any ideas?

Comment: @Stuart Kuredjian If Version.class is in src/zetcode and fully qualified name of this class is zetcode.Version my suggestion should work.

Comment: Right. Which is why I posted the results of I got when I did what you recommended. Obv. I'm missing something.  It executes fine in Eclipse, just not from the terminal. Can you put a folder on your desktop, run it from command line and if it works, zip it as is and put it on dropbox so I can try in the same exact environment as you?

Comment: ka4ak can you just recheck the part after the semicolon in your suggestion?  Because when I do it your way it says "-bash: src: command not found.  So it's reading "src" as a command and not as you intended.  thanks.

Comment: @Stuart Kuredjian Sorry, I've forgotten that the delimiter is OS dependent. Answer has been edited.