# Executing Java on Ubuntu gives gibberish output

Tags: java, ubuntu, jar

*(Update below based on comments and answers)*

---

I've developed some Java on Windows, and I've executed it successfully on that machine. For the first time, I'm attempting to execute it on Ubuntu. I installed OpenJDK-7-jre, and have copied the jars and source code over.

The jars:

```
(djauth_venv)~/django_files/django_auth_lifecycle/non_django_files/wordpress_posts/build$ ls -la dependency_jars/
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jeffy jeffy 185140 Jun 12  2012 commons-io-2.4.jar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jeffy jeffy  18863 Dec 11 12:53 templatefeather-0.1.1.2.jar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jeffy jeffy 665303 Dec 11 12:52 xbnjava-0.1.5.jar
```

When attempting to execute it with

`java BuildPartFour -classpath /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/rt.jar;/home/jeffy/django_files/django_auth_lifecycle/non_django_files/wordpress_posts/build/dependency_jars/commons-io-2.4.jar;/home/jeffy/django_files/django_auth_lifecycle/non_django_files/wordpress_posts/build/dependency_jars/templatefeather-0.1.1.2.jar;/home/jeffy/django_files/django_auth_lifecycle/non_django_files/wordpress_posts/build/dependency_jars/xbnjava-0.1.5.jar`

It results in permission denied for each of the jars:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/github/xbn/io/PlainTextFileUtil
        at BuildPartFour.main(BuildPartFour.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.github.xbn.io.PlainTextFileUtil
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        ... 1 more
-bash: /home/jeffy/django_files/django_auth_lifecycle/non_django_files/wordpress_posts/build/dependency_jars/commons-io-2.4.jar: Permission denied
-bash: /home/jeffy/django_files/django_auth_lifecycle/non_django_files/wordpress_posts/build/dependency_jars/templatefeather-0.1.1.2.jar: Permission denied
-bash: /home/jeffy/django_files/django_auth_lifecycle/non_django_files/wordpress_posts/build/dependency_jars/xbnjava-0.1.5.jar: Permission denied
```

I've changed the jars to be executable

```
(djauth_venv)jeffy@originaldjangster:~/django_files/django_auth_lifecycle/non_django_files/wordpress_posts/build$ chmod 774 dependency_jars/*.jar
(djauth_venv)jeffy@originaldjangster:~/django_files/django_auth_lifecycle/non_django_files/wordpress_posts/build$ ls -la dependency_jars/               total 864
-rwxrwxr-- 1 jeffy jeffy 185140 Jun 12  2012 commons-io-2.4.jar
-rwxrwxr-- 1 jeffy jeffy  18863 Dec 11 12:53 templatefeather-0.1.1.2.jar
-rwxrwxr-- 1 jeffy jeffy 665303 Dec 11 12:52 xbnjava-0.1.5.jar
```

But now, when attempting to execute it again, I get this crazy output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/github/xbn/io/PlainTextFileUtil
        at BuildPartFour.main(BuildPartFour.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.github.xbn.io.PlainTextFileUtil
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        ... 1 more
/home/jeffy/django_files/django_auth_lifecycle/non_django_files/wordpress_posts/build/dependency_jars/commons-io-2.4.jar: line 1: $'PK\003\004': command not found
/home/jeffy/django_files/django_auth_lifecycle/non_django_files/wordpress_posts/build/dependency_jars/commons-io-2.4.jar: line 2: $'v\222\314@': command not found
/home/jeffy/django_files/django_auth_lifecycle/non_django_files/wordpress_posts/build/dependency_jars/commons-io-2.4.jar: line 21: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
/home/jeffy/django_files/django_auth_lifecycle/non_django_files/wordpress_posts/build/dependency_jars/commons-io-2.4.jar: line 21: `▒Ғ▒^w▒ ▒▒W▒!▒▒
N▒
  g▒▒1^▒yKn▒K(▒"▒N▒▒▒
▒F/L*▒vTb6▒▒▒▒l4]▒▒▒hL▒F▒▒▒▒`▒l▒8m▒C▒▒▒▒▒▒▒u▒▒▒A▒*▒O▒▒▒▒6Jys▒▒C%▒▒݅Z▒ب▒&▒@▒▒▒9▒▒▒^▒"▒ID_▒▒▒▒$ +yr.,▒▒趒3▒a▒▒O▒▒▒eq▒▒e▒M▒5|▒Ȓ;▒▒▒=▒<])_▒pڔ▒▒▒D▒▒▒írU$▒E▒+'
/home/jeffy/django_files/django_auth_lifecycle/non_django_files/wordpress_posts/build/dependency_jars/templatefeather-0.1.1.2.jar: line 1: $'PK\003\004': command not found
/home/jeffy/django_files/django_auth_lifecycle/non_django_files/wordpress_posts/build/dependency_jars/templatefeather-0.1.1.2.jar: line 2: $'\b\245f\213E': command not found
/home/jeffy/django_files/django_auth_lifecycle/non_django_files/wordpress_posts/build/dependency_jars/templatefeather-0.1.1.2.jar: line 3▒f▒E2▒f▒ZgMETA-K-*▒▒ϳR0▒3▒▒r▒Cq,HL▒HU▒%-▒Lx▒▒▒RKRSt▒*A▒▒▒
▒͍t▒
M4▒▒sR▒▒: No such file or directory
/home/jeffy/django_files/django_auth_lifecycle/non_django_files/wordpress_posts/build/dependency_jars/templatefeather-0.1.1.2.jar: line 4: $'\362\213\022K\200\3725y\271x\271PK\003\004': command not found
/home/jeffy/django_files/django_auth_lifecycle/non_django_files/wordpress_posts/build/dependency_jars/templatefeather-0.1.1.2.jar: line 5:{f▒Ecom/PK: No such file or directory
/home/jeffy/django_files/django_auth_lifecycle/non_django_files/wordpress_posts/build/dependency_jars/templatefeather-0.1.1.2.jar: line 6: f▒E com/github/PK: No such file or directory
/home/jeffy/django_files/django_auth_lifecycle/non_django_files/wordpress_posts/build/dependency_jars/templatefeather-0.1.1.2.jar: line 6: $'\b': command not found
/home/jeffy/django_files/django_auth_lifecycle/non_django_files/wordpress_posts/build/dependency_jars/templatefeather-0.1.1.2.jar: line 7: f▒Ecom/github/aliteralmind/PK: No such file or directory
/home/jeffy/django_files/django_auth_lifecycle/non_django_files/wordpress_posts/build/dependency_jars/templatefeather-0.1.1.2.jar: line 7: $'\b': command not found
/home/jeffy/django_files/django_auth_lifecycle/non_django_files/wordpress_posts/build/dependency_jars/templatefeather-0.1.1.2.jar: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `$'com/github/aliteralmind/templatefeather/PK\003\004''
/home/jeffy/django_files/django_auth_lifecycle/non_django_files/wordpress_posts/build/dependency_jars/templatefeather-0.1.1.2.jar: line 8: |f▒E(com/github/aliteralmind/templatefeather/PK'
/home/jeffy/django_files/django_auth_lifecycle/non_django_files/wordpress_posts/build/dependency_jars/xbnjava-0.1.5.jar: line 1: $'PK\003\004': command not found
/home/jeffy/django_files/django_auth_lifecycle/non_django_files/wordpress_posts/build/dependency_jars/xbnjava-0.1.5.jar: line 2: $'\b\214f\213E': command not found
/home/jeffy/django_files/django_auth_lifecycle/non_django_files/wordpress_posts/build/dependency_jars/xbnjava-0.1.5.jar: line 3▒f▒E2▒f▒ZgMETA-INF/MANIFEK-*▒▒ϳR0▒3▒▒r▒Cq,HL▒HU▒%-▒Lx▒▒▒RKRSt▒*A▒▒▒
▒͍t▒
M4▒▒sR▒▒: No such file or directory
/home/jeffy/django_files/django_auth_lifecycle/non_django_files/wordpress_posts/build/dependency_jars/xbnjava-0.1.5.jar: line 4: $'\362\213\022K\200\3725y\271x\271PK\003\004': command not found
/home/jeffy/django_files/django_auth_lifecycle/non_django_files/wordpress_posts/build/dependency_jars/xbnjava-0.1.5.jar: line 5:tf▒Ecom/PK: No such file or directory
/home/jeffy/django_files/django_auth_lifecycle/non_django_files/wordpress_posts/build/dependency_jars/xbnjava-0.1.5.jar: line 6:tf▒E com/github/PK: No such file or directory
/home/jeffy/django_files/django_auth_lifecycle/non_django_files/wordpress_posts/build/dependency_jars/xbnjava-0.1.5.jar: line 7:zf▒Ecom/github/xbn/PK: No such file or directory
/home/jeffy/django_files/django_auth_lifecycle/non_django_files/wordpress_posts/build/dependency_jars/xbnjava-0.1.5.jar: line 8:tf▒Ecom/github/xbn/analyze/PK: No such file or directory
/home/jeffy/django_files/django_auth_lifecycle/non_django_files/wordpress_posts/build/dependency_jars/xbnjava-0.1.5.jar: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `$'ʭ\210\342A''
/home/jeffy/django_files/django_auth_lifecycle/non_django_files/wordpress_posts/build/dependency_jars/xbnjava-0.1.5.jar: line 9:tf▒E▒U▒M_-com/github/xbn/analyze/AbstractAnalyzer.class▒▒yS▒@Ɵ▒j!(ʭ▒▒A'
(djauth_venv)jeffy@originaldjangster:~/django_files/django_auth_lifecycle/non_django_files/wordpress_posts/build$ PuTTY
```

Earlier today, I successfully executed this via SFTP on my Windows machine. It's horribly slow, but it works. What do I need to do to execute this directly in Ubuntu?

Thanks.

---

***Updated based on comments and answer***

Thank you, @Alex and @ChrisStratton. After making the jars non-executable again and using colons, I'm no longer getting the gibberish, but it still gives me

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/github/xbn/io/PlainTextFileUtil
at BuildPartFour.main(BuildPartFour.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.github.xbn.io.PlainTextFileUtil`.
```

This class is indeed in the jar:

```
$7z l /home/jeffy/django_files/django_auth_lifecycle/non_django_files/wordpress_posts/build/dependency_jars/xbnjava-0.1.5.jar

7-Zip 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
p7zip Version 9.20 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,1 CPU)

Listing archive: /home/jeffy/django_files/django_auth_lifecycle/non_django_files/wordpress_posts/build/dependency_jars/xbnjava-0.1.5.jar


--
Path = /home/jeffy/django_files/django_auth_lifecycle/non_django_files/wordpress_posts/build/dependency_jars/xbnjava-0.1.5.jar

Type = zip
Physical Size = 665303

   Date      Time    Attr         Size   Compressed  Name
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
2014-12-11 12:52:24 D....            0            0  META-INF
2014-12-11 12:52:22 .....          103           90  META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
2014-12-11 12:51:40 D....            0            0  com
2014-12-11 12:51:40 D....            0            0  com/github
2014-12-11 12:51:52 D....            0            0  com/github/xbn

...

2014-12-11 12:51:40 .....         5523         2651  com/github/xbn/io/IOUtil.class
2014-12-11 12:51:40 .....         2483         1098  com/github/xbn/io/MultiTextAppender.class
2014-12-11 12:51:40 .....         2018          865  com/github/xbn/io/NewPrintWriterToFile.class
2014-12-11 12:51:40 .....         2497          927  com/github/xbn/io/NewTextAppenderFor.class
2014-12-11 12:51:40 .....         1687          685  com/github/xbn/io/NewTextAppenterFor.class
2014-12-11 12:51:40 .....         5655         2311  com/github/xbn/io/PathMustBe.class
2014-12-11 12:51:40 .....         2250          906  com/github/xbn/io/PlainTextFileUtil.class
2014-12-11 12:51:40 .....         1656          871  com/github/xbn/io/PrintStreamForString.class
2014-12-11 12:51:40 .....          458          292  com/github/xbn/io/RTAccessDeniedException.class
2014-12-11 12:51:40 .....          450          288  com/github/xbn/io/RTEndOfFileException.class
2014-12-11 12:51:40 .....          458          288  com/github/xbn/io/RTFileNotFoundException.class

...

------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
                               1437122       545645  621 files, 49 folders
```

What am I still missing?

Comment: You don't execute a `.jar` - Java simply needs access. It looks like the class files are corrupted.

Comment: Yes - the semicolons are causing a unix shell to see the jars as distinct commands.  On linux use a colon. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528438/classpath-does-not-work-under-linux

Comment: possible duplicate of [Classpath does not work under linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528438/classpath-does-not-work-under-linux)

Comment: @ChrisStratton: I've updated the question. Your advice got me a significant step further.

Comment: There is a backquote after `PlainTextFileUtil` in your last stack trace; question edit error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The jars do not need to be executable

On Windows, the semantics are

```
java -classpath somejar1.jar;somejar2.jar
```

But on *NIX, the semantics are

```
java -classpath somejar1.jar:somejar2.jar
```

*NIX needs colons (`:`) not semi-colons (`;`).

**UPDATE**

It looks like your command is incorrectly structured, you said you're doing this:

```
java BuildPartFour -classpath (...)
```

Where I'm assuming BuildPartFour is a .class file in the current working directory.  This would result in running your BuildPartFour class passing in `-classpath (...)` as arguments to your program (these would be visible in the `public static void main(String[] args)` args array

It should be this:

```
java -classpath (...) BuildPartFour
```

The general java command structure is:

```
java [options] [class] [args]
```

Comment: I've updated the question. This has gotten me a significant step further.

Comment: Yes, this. Currently `-classpath` is being passed as an argument to the application, **not** the JVM.

Comment: That's it. I've forgotten the basics. Actually, it was necessary to add a "." to the classpath, in order to find the class-to-be-executed itself.

Comment: Final command is `java -classpath .:/home/jeffy/django_files/django_auth_lifecycle/non_django_files/wordpress_posts/build/dependency_jars/xbnjava-0.1.5.1.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/rt.jar:/home/jeffy/django_files/django_auth_lifecycle/non_django_files/wordpress_posts/build/dependency_jars/commons-io-2.4.jar:/home/jeffy/django_files/django_auth_lifecycle/non_django_files/wordpress_posts/build/dependency_jars/templatefeather-0.1.1.3.jar BuildPartFour`