# Error when using java -classpath command

Tags: java

I have a class, test, as follows

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.ini4j.InvalidFileFormatException;
import org.ini4j.Wini;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidFileFormatException, IOException{
        File f = new File("ini.ini");
        Wini ini = new Wini(f);
        int a = ini.get("test", "a", int.class);
        int b = ini.get("test", "b", int.class);
        int c = ini.get("test", "c", int.class);

        System.out.print(a);
        System.out.print(b);
        System.out.print(c);
    }
}
```

To compile I run the command

`javac -classpath ini4j-0.5.4.jar test.java`

which compiles without issue, but when I try to run it with the command

`java -classpath ini4j-0.5.4.jar test`

I get the error `Error: Could not find or load main class test`.

If I exclude the `-classpath ini4j-0.5.4.jar` from the `java .. test` command I get an error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/ini4j/InvalidFileFormatException ...`

The class runs fine in eclipse.

Comment: Did you try using wildcards along with it?

Comment: @XOR No I haven't, could you give me a code sample of what you mean exactly?

Comment: When you specify the `-classpath` parameter, it overrides the *entire* classpath, which means that the current directory `.` isn't included anymore the way you're doing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the directory your compiled class file ends up into your classpath in your java invocation.

In your case

```
java -cp "ini4j-0.5.4.jar:." test
```

would be what you want, since everything is in the current working directory.

Edit: Updated for completeness ^^.  The class path uses a system specific path separator.  So for the unfortunate souls using windows it would be:

```
java -cp "ini4j-0.5.4.jar;." test
```

Comment: this answer is OS -specific, e.g. it will fail on Windows, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528438/classpath-does-not-work-under-linux

Comment: @SergeyPauk is correct, it gives the same error as the original command

Comment: if you are on Windows then replace the colon with a semicolon in the answer above

Comment: changing the colon to a semi colon fixed it

Comment: @lscoughlin it's not about being pedantic but about the completeness of a given answer (as it turned out the author is indeed an unfortunate windows user :)

Comment: @SergeyPauk Fair enough ^^