# Classpath fails in rhel 7 environment

Tags: java, ubuntu, rhel

I have a huge problem with a bash script that compile java code, all the variables are defined correctly and when I try it in Ubuntu it goes fine with PATH and JAVA_HOME well defined...but when I run the SAME script in rhel 7 environment (same variables, same script, same code and java version) I get a lot of errors like

```
error: package comun.util does not exist import
comun.util.GestorLogger;
```

But CLASSPATH its fine, I check it, even when I export it prior to the script

How can this be possible?, Same script, variables and java fails in rhel but goes fine in Ubuntu?

What am I missing? are there any other variables that I'm skipping?

Comment: See definition about CLASSPATH separator: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4528456/1075369

Comment: two things to try: run ``ps axu |grep java`` and see what "-classpath" is actually set to in the running process. If the java program won't even start and is started from a shell script run the script as ``sh -vx scriptname`` and look at how it interpolates the variables.