# Can not find or load class with Java ProcessBuilder using -cp and jar location

Tags: java, junit, classpath, processbuilder

I am trying to use `ProcessBuilder` to start a JUnit test within my `Java` Application.

I am able to run the same command from the command line without issue.  Do I need to use the absolute path for the jar when running from ProcessBuilder or can I use the relative path?

**Running on the command line**

```
java -cp .;lib/junit-4.12.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore com.test.Test1
```

**Running inside my application**

The junit library is in the lib folder

application/lib/junit-4.12.jar

```
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(new String[] {"java", "-cp", ".;lib/junit-4.12.jar", "com.test.Test1"});

        Process process = builder.start();
        process.waitFor();

        debug("process ended");
        debug("process.exitValue() = " + process.exitValue());
```

Output:

```
process ended
process.exitValue() = 1
Error: Could not find or load main class org.junit.runner.JUnitCore
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find what the classpath is when you run your application by using 
`System.getProperty("java.class.path");`
Then, modify "cp" in your `ProcessBuilder()` statement accordingly.

Comment: How can I use more than one libarary in my -cp in the `ProcessBuilder` statement it seems to not find it once I have more than one  "one.jar;two.jar" will fail but "one.jar" will work.

Comment: You can use yet another system property `System.getProperty("path.separator");` to find the right separator character. They are OS-dependent. See also other SO posts on the subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528438/classpath-does-not-work-under-linux

Answer (score 0):

Set the base directory for the ProcessBuilder you are wanting to use.

```
File libDir = new File("/opt/app/lib");
builder.directory(libDir);
```

This is the solution I ended up using after @mazaneicha 's comment to relook at the app's classpath directory.