# Error while executing the java program

Tags: java

```
java -cp .;/home/<user name>/enginex/lib/lucene.jar Main.class
```

shows the error /home//enginex/lib/lucene.jar  is not a file or directory while the path is correct.

Comment: Please actually paste the error in your question

Comment: Are you *sure* the path is correct? Java thinks otherwise

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528438/classpath-does-not-work-under-linux - `java -cp .:/ho...`

Comment: <user name> doesn't appear to be resolving.  Are you sure that is the correct variable name?  Maybe it's <user_name>?

Comment: @Matt1776 I'm guessing they just want to hide their computer's user name...

Comment: <user name> is just replaced for user name. I used colon and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The semicolon should not be there. You should change it with a colon.