# Linux equivalent of including the classpath during compilation

Tags: java

I'm following a guide that only includes compilation instructions on windows. How would one run this `build.bat` file on Linux?

The batch file looks like this:

```
@echo off
@echo Compiling...
javac -classpath ..\..\lib\OneWireAPI.jar;%classpath% -d . .\src\*.java
```

And when I run the `javac` command on Linux, it fails:

```
javac -classpath ../../lib/OneWireAPI.jar;%classpath% -d . ./src/ReadTemp.java
```

The output is:

```
javac: no source files
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: I think you are looking for ":" instead of ";"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Classpath does not work under linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528438/classpath-does-not-work-under-linux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux, you have to use `:` (colon) in place of `;` (semicolon) as the path separator in Java options.

Also, if you have a `classpath` variable, in most common Linux shells it is referenced by `$classpath` rather than by `%classpath%`

```
javac -classpath ../../lib/OneWireAPI.jar:$classpath -d . ./src/ReadTemp.java
```

Comment: Beat me by 7 seconds :)

Comment: Also, probably need to capitalize CLASSPATH

Comment: It depends: environment variables are usually uppercase, but can also be lowercase. It just matters to use the same case in declaration and use.

Answer (score 1):

You have two items that did not get translated correctly from Windows CMD to Unix:

- Path separator `;` should be `:`.
- Environment variables should be changed from `%classpath%` to `$CLASSPATH` format. Note that pretty much everything is case-sensitive in Linux, including environment variable names, and the Java path is traditionally all-caps.

Try

```
javac -classpath ../../lib/OneWireAPI.jar:$CLASSPATH -d . ./src/ReadTemp.java
```