# Running Test NG test suite from command line - Error: Could not find or load main class org.testng.TestNG

Tags: command-line, testng

As the title says
I tried to follow the clues mentioned in

[How to run TestNG from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896791/how-to-run-testng-from-command-line)

but I get `Error: Could not find or load main class org.testng.TestNG`

Here is the detailed command I use:

```
java -cp "testng-6.8.jar:C:\Users\...\src\test\java\unit_tests\libs_test" org.testng.TestNG "C:\Users\...\src\test\resources\AllUnitTests.xml"
```

The point is that when I opened testng-6.8.jar in 7zip, I can see the org.testng.TestNG class:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spYKT.jpg)

What is wrong with that command?

Comment: I think you should be using `;` (since you are on windows) instead of using `:` (which is applicable for UNIX) as a separator between the jars. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4528456/679824)

Comment: Thanks Krishnan, but that didin't help, although the error message is slightly different.
  Error: Unable to initialize main class org.testng.TestNG
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/beust/jcommander/ParameterException