# Moving Javac compile command from OSX to Windows

Tags: java

I am compiling a java program that I know works. In OSX I have a classpath of

```
$ echo $CLASSPATH
/Users/<REDACTED>/SoftwareDownload/MySpecialFolder/lib/Wrap.jar:.
```

I can then compile using

```
javac MyPullOne.java
```

Now in windows i have set $PATH to be

```
Y:\MySpecialFolder\lib\Wrap.jar
```

No luck.

I also tried

```
javac -cp 'Y:\MySepcialFolder\lib\Wrap.jar:.' MyPullOne.java
```

Still no luck. How do I essentially move over the "CLASSPATH" variable? What is it's windows 10 equivalent?

Comment: The path won't be `Y:\MySepcialFolder\lib\Wrap.jar:.`, but will probably be `Y:\MySepcialFolder\lib\Wrap.jar;.`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Classpath does not work under linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528438/classpath-does-not-work-under-linux)

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096283/including-jars-in-classpath-on-commandline-javac-or-apt

Comment: On windows you should also set CLASSPATH, not PATHlike you wrote in your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Widows, the classpath separator is the semicolon, not the colon.