# How to execute terminal PITest?

Tags: java, windows, terminal

I need to execute PITest for a project using the terminal like in this link http://pitest.org/quickstart/commandline/. I cannot use mvn for this exercise, so I need to do it using java in the terminal.

I try this:

```
java -cp C:\\Users\\Federico\\Documents\\Projects\\pitestVSCodeExtension\\PiTEST\\pitest-1.4.9.jar:C:\\Users\\Federico\\Documents\\Projects\pitestVSCodeExtension\\PiTEST\\pitest-command-line-1.4.9.jar:C:\\Users\\Federico\\Documents\\Projects\pitestVSCodeExtension\\PiTEST\\pitest-entry-1.4.9.jar org.pitest.mutationtest.commandline.MutationCoverageReport --reportDir C:\\Users\\Federico\\Documents\\Projects\\pitestVSCodeExtension --targetClasses org.autotest.* --sourceDirs C:\\Users\\Federico\\Documents\\Projects\\pitestVSCodeExtension\\Stack\\src --targetTests org.autotest*
```

The result was this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.pitest.mutationtest.commandline.MutationCoverageReport
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.pitest.mutationtest.commandline.MutationCoverageReport
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're on Windows and using `:` as a path separator? This should be a `;` in your case. Please refer to [Classpath does not work under linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528438/classpath-does-not-work-under-linux) for details.